# How to mark code warning as irrelevant in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, suppress-warnings

I have a snippet of R code using magrittr pipes on a matrix.
I need to access some column of the matrix and it works like a charm:

```
# library(magrittr) || library(tidyverse)
installed.packages() %>% 
    magrittr::extract(, "Package")
```

However, RStudio complains about the last line with the warning "missing argument to function call".

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of the warning without changing the code?
For example adding a special comment to the line such as `##nowarn`?

I think RStudio uses ace if it's a feature of the editor.

---

**Additional info:**

- R 3.4.2 on Windows 7 x64
- magrittr Version 1.5
- RStudio Desktop Version 1.1.383

Comment: I don't see that warning, maybe add `sessionInfo()` to your post? `R version 3.4.2, magrittr_1.5` And RStudio version, too. `Version 1.1.453`

Comment: Maybe use dplyr? `installed.packages() %>% as_data_frame %>% pull(Package)`

Comment: An alternative solution is to use curly brackets to tell `magrittr` that you will take control over the `.` component: `installed_packages %>% {.[, "Package"]}`.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for your help. Have you saved the code snippet to a file such as `tmp.R`? I had to do that for the warning to appear.  
RE alternative: `as_tibble()` will complain if colnames is `NULL`. The actual use case has a character matrix without names.

Comment: @DuckPyjamas That's an option but I would prefer to disable the warning so I can keep the readability of the original code.

Comment: Symptom fix is: go to `tools > global options > code > diagnostics` there uncheck `Check arguments to R function calls`. This is harmless if you have habit of calling function with `function (argument name = argument value)`

Comment: You need to apply above change and then save the file or probably close and reopen the file for that warning to disappear

Comment: @abhiieor Thanks for the hint, but even a complete restart of RStudio doesn't permanently disable the warning :(, Completely disabling R Code Diagnostics does work, though...

Comment: OK, after saving I see the warning, too. I understand the problem, but for such trivial task why not avoid magrittr? e.g.: `installed.packages()[, "Package"]`

Comment: @zx8754 For the example this is true, but my actual code is a series of string manipulations involving str_match. That outputs a matrix of strings and I need to access only some columns for further processing.